# What is time complexity for find method in a set in c++?

Tags: c++, stl, find, set

```
set<int> s;

s.insert(1);
s.insert(2);
...
s.insert(n);
```

I wonder how much time it takes for `s.find(k)` where `k` is a number from 1..n?
I assume it is log(n). Is it correct?

Comment: Do you mean "log(n)" instead of "n log(n)"?

Answer (score 21):

O( log N ) to search for an individual element.

§23.1.2 Table 69

```
expression  return            note                                   complexity
a.find(k)   iterator;         returns an iterator pointing to an     logarithmic
            const_iterator    element with the key equivalent to k, 
            for constant a    or a.end() if such an element is not 
                              found
```

Comment: Good information, but §23.1.2 Table 69 isn't much good without the name of the book.

Comment: @snibbets: When dealing with a standarized language, the book is the standard. At the point of the answer that would be C++03 standard. In the current C++11 standard this would be §23.2.4 Table 102.

Answer (score 5):

The complexity of `std::set::find()` being `O(log(n))` simply means that there will be of the order of `log(n)` comparisons of objects stored in the `set`.

If the complexity of the comparison of 2 elements in the set is `O(k)` , then the actual complexity, would be `O(log(n)∗k)`.
 this can happen for example in case of set of strings (k would be the length of the longest string) as the comparison of 2 strings may imply comparing most of (or all) of their characters (if they start with the same prefix or are equal)

The [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/find/) says the same:

> #### Complexity
>
> Logarithmic in size.