# How can I implement Python sets in another language (maybe C++)?

Tags: c++, python, c, arrays, algorithm

I want to translate some Python code that I have already written to C++ or another fast language because Python isn't quite fast enough to do what I want to do. However the code in question abuses some of the impressive features of Python sets, specifically the average O(1) membership testing which I spam within performance critical loops, and I am unsure of how to implement Python sets in another language.

In [Python's Time Complexity Wiki Page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), it states that sets have O(1) membership testing on average and in worst-case O(n). I tested this personally using `timeit` and was astonished by how blazingly fast Python sets do membership testing, even with large N. I looked at [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790993/what-is-time-complexity-for-find-method-in-a-set-in-c) to see how C++ sets compare when using `find` operations to see if an element is a member of a given set and it said that it is O(log(n)).

I hypothesize the time complexity for `find` is logarithmic in that C++ std library sets are implemented with some sort of binary tree. I think that because Python sets have average O(1) membership testing and worst case O(n), they are probably implemented with some sort of associative array with buckets which can just look up an element with ease and test it for some dummy value which indicates that the element is not part of the set.

The thing is, I don't want to slow down any part of my code by switching to another language (since that is the problem im trying to fix in the first place) so how could I implement my own version of Python sets (specifically just the fast membership testing) in another language? Does anybody know anything about how Python sets are implemented, and if not, could anyone give me any general hints to point me in the right direction?

I'm not looking for source code, just general ideas and links that will help me get started.

I have done a bit of research on [Associative Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) and I think I understand the basic idea behind their implementation but I'm unsure of their memory usage. If Python sets are indeed just really associative arrays, how can I implement them with a minimal use of memory?

Additional note: The sets in question that I want to use will have up to 50,000 elements and each element of the set will be in a large range (say [-999999999, 999999999]).

Comment: If you want O(1) lookup in C++, use [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set).  However, 50k elements is not that many, it should take less than 16 comparisons to do a lookup in a standard `std::set`.

Comment: I definitely want O(1) lookup since I have multiple lookups within a loop. Thanks for the link to unordered_sets, I didn't know the std library had that. That will probably save me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The theoretical difference betwen `O(1)` and `O(log n)` means very little in practice, especially when comparing two different languages. `log n` is small for most practical values of `n`. Constant factors of each implementation are easily more significant.
2. C++11 has `unordered_set` and `unordered_map` now. Even if you cannot use C++11, there are always the Boost version and the tr1 version (the latter is named `hash_*` instead of `unordered_*`).

Comment: Thanks, I will take your advice to mind. I'll try it first with just `set` and if that isn't fast enough I'll use `unordered_set`. I guess when I think about it O(log(n)) isn't really that big for an n of 50k.

Comment: @ShashankGupta On one test I ran many, many years ago, the break-even point (between `std::set` and my implementation of a hash table) was around 100K elements.  This very much depends on _what_ is in the set, however; `std::set` is O(lg n) on the number of comparisons; `std::unordered_set` is O(1), _if_ you have a good hash function.  Depending on the data, calculating a good hash may require as much time as dozens, or more comparisons.  On not.  It depends on the data.  (FWIW: Python uses a hash table.  And if you create your own type, and give it a bad `__hash__`, it will be very slow.)

Answer (score 2):

Several points: you have, as has been pointed out, `std::set` and
`std::unordered_set` (the latter only in C++11, but most compilers have
offered something similar as an extension for many years now).  The
first is implemented by some sort of balanced tree (usually a red-black
tree), the second as a hash_table.  Which one is faster depends on the
data type: the first requires some sort of ordering relationship (e.g.
`<` if it is defined on the type, but you can define your own); the
second an equivalence relationship (`==`, for example) and a hash
function compatible with this equivalence relationship.  The first is
O(lg n), the second O(1), *if* you have a good hash function.  Thus:

- If comparison for order is significantly faster than hashing,
  `std::set` may actually be faster, at least for "smaller" data sets,
  where "smaller" depends on how large the difference is—for
  strings, for example, the comparison will often resolve after the first
  couple of characters, whereas the hash code will look at every
  character.  In one experiment I did (many years back), with strings of
  30-50 characters, I found the break even point to be about 100000
  elements.
- For some data types, simply finding a good hash function which is
  compatible with the type may be difficult.  Python uses a hash table for
  its set, and if you define a type with a function `__hash__` that always
  returns 1, it will be very, very slow.  Writing a good hash function
  isn't always obvious.
- Finally, both are node based containers, which means they use a lot
  more memory than e.g. `std::vector`, with very poor locality.  If lookup
  is the predominant operation, you might want to consider `std::vector`,
  keeping it sorted and using `std::lower_bound` for the lookup.
  Depending on the type, this can result in a significant speed-up, and
  much less memory use.