# Time complexity algorithms with conditionals

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm doing an algorithm to check if a given string is a permutation of a palindrome (eg. "Tact Coa" is a permutation of "taco cat"). My algorithm ignores whitespaces and is case insensitive. Below is my implementation:

```
bool isPalindromePermutation(string str) {
    set<char> s;

    // Convert to lower case
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
        if (str[i] >= 65 && str[i] <= 90) {
            str[i] += 32;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
        // find() is O(log n)
        bool contains = s.find(str[i]) != s.end();
        // Ignore whitespace
        if (str[i] != ' ') {
            if (contains) {
                s.erase(str[i]);
            }
            else {
                s.insert(str[i]);
            }
        }

    }

    return s.empty() || s.size() == 1;
}
```

The time complexity I have worked out until now is O(n log n), since I iterate over each character of the string (which is O(n)), and for each character I look it up in the set which is [O(log n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790993/what-is-time-complexity-for-find-method-in-a-set-in-c), giving me O(n log n).
The part that confuses me is how to deal with the conditionals. Do I have to assume that they are always executed?

Also, I know that the complexity of a set `insert()` is [O(log n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776485/complexity-of-setinsert). But I'm confused about the `erase()` method (read [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase#Complexity))

What would be the complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: It's pretty easy to find out the actual time complexity of something. Benchmark it with varying values of *n* and graph the results. Find the curve that fits that shape the closest.

Comment: Why are you using the constants 65/90. You can use (is it) 'A' and 'Z'?

Comment: Don't forget to use `const string&` in preference to `string` as that will avoid needless copies.

Comment: Your algorithm is too complex, think about what is a palindrome and how you can rearrange the letters to find the same words for all words that are palindromes. Will make your program much much simpler and its complexity much easier to compute

Comment: I know this isn't the most efficient algorithm, perhaps sorting the string would help. But I'd still like to know how to deal with conditionals inside loops.

Comment: Nitpick: The set lookup is O(26) since you only deal with lowercase letters of the alphabet. Even if you used the whole char range, it would be O(2^CHAR_BITS), typically O(256). In any case, it's not O(n), assuming n is the number of elements in the input sequence.

Comment: Actually, make that O(log 26) and O(CHAR_BITS), the latter using the fact that log 2^CHAR_BIT = CHAR_BIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to treat conditionals?**

If you want O, you are trying to compute an upper limit. Here, I'd simply assume as worst case that either one or the other branch is always called. Then, determine the according complexity of each branch. The upper limit of both branches is the maximum complexity of the two branches, simple as that.

In your case, you could go a step further though: There is a fixed limit K to the number of elements in the set. Further, if you inserted an element in one iteration, the next iteration with the same value will erase the element again. So, after inserting K elements in the set, you know that the next iteration must remove an element again. That means, if only you make enough iterations, you have similar amounts of inserts and deletions, they only differ by K, which becomes negligible. If the two branches are O(a) and O(b), the combined complexity is therefore O((a+b)/2 + c) = O((a+b)/2).

**What's the complexity of the erase operation?**

You found the documentation already. Check it out again, it's the third form of the `erase()` call, which is "log(c.size()) + c.count(k)". "c.count(k)" is exactly one. "log(c.size())" depends on the maximum size of the set, which is bounded by its type, in this case `char`, 2^CHAR_BITS in this case. The logarithm thereof is CHAR_BITS, typically 8. In summary, the complexity is constant.

**What is the overall complexity of the algorithm?**

You pretty much found it yourself, you only missed the point that the size of the set is bounded to a value that doesn't depend on the input size. With n being the size of the input sequence, this makes inserts, lookups and erases O(1), making the whole algorithm O(n).